# Flutter TextButton splashColor property

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I was using `FlatButton` and passed the properties

```
FlatButton(
      splashColor: Colors.transparent,
      highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
      child: ..., 
)
```

The [documentation says that FlatButton will become obsolete](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FlatButton-class.html), and to use `TextButton` instead, but it does not take `splashColor` or `highlightColor` properties

```
TextButton(                  
    splashColor: Colors.transparent,
    highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
    child: ...,       
)
```

does not work. it is not allowed

I also tried like this

```
TextButton(            
  style: ButtonStyle(
    splashColor: Colors.transparent,
    highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
  ),
  child: ..., 
)
```

How can I do this? Thank you

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Colors.transparent will deny any effects, simply it is transparent so it will appear as nothing happens... in ButtonStyle, it goes something like this with colors.

```
ButtonStyle(
   overlayColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.red),
),
```

Comment: Yes, I want transparent, this is a web project and I don't want the bubbles when you click. In this example I can't replace overlayColor with splashColor but it seems it removed the effect. Why do I have to use MaterialStateColor with this TextButton instead of just Color? What does it mean?

Answer (score 24):

As Flat button is depricated, you have to use TextButton instead of it, but in text button there is no direct property to change splash color. So if you want to change splash color to transparent you can do it like this.

```
TextButton(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent),
  ),
)
```

Comment: It seems it works for all types of buttons, including ElevatedButton. Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

You can also use like this

```
 TextButton( onPressed: () {},
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                              backgroundColor: AppColors.primaryColor,
                              primary: Colors.black12),//ripple color
                          child:Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).startAdventure,
                          ));
```

*You can Set **primary** color to create ripple color*

Comment: No, the primary property on a TextButton sets the colour of its text (and icon, if its TextButton.icon). It does not change the ripple color.

Comment: I have been using this in my project, It seems working fine actually!
@Marvioso Have you tested my code?

Comment: Hey, I've just re-tested the code and it works actually! The primary colour sets the colour of the text, but it also sets a very faint (low opacity) colour to the ripple animation. If you wanted a different text colour than the set primary colour, you can set this in the textstyle property. Good catch Balaji

Answer (score 8):

For Flutter over 3.1.0, where *primary* is deprecated, I change the spash color using:

```
style: TextButton.styleFrom(
   backgroundColor: Colors.green,  // Button color
   foregroundColor: Colors.lime,   // Splash color
),
child:Text(...)
```

In case it helps!

Answer (score 5):

*Using theme, it will be applied to all TextButtons in your project*

Put this inside themeData:

```
textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
    style: ButtonStyle(
      splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
      overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 5):

Using just `copyWith` :

```
  TextButton(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                primary:  Colors.red,
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    ).copyWith(
                       overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent)),
    )
```

Answer (score 4):

For someone who is not familiar to `MaterialStateProperty` setting in TextButton (use `resolveWith` to customize the button effect):

```
TextButton(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    overlayColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) {
      if(states.contains(MaterialState.hover){
        return Colors.transparent; // <- hover color
      }else if(states.contains(MaterialState.pressed){
        return Colors.transparent; // <- ripple color
      }
      ...
    },
    backgroundColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) {
      if(states.contains(MaterialState.pressed){
        return Colors.transparent; // <- clicked color
      }
      ...
    }),
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define your desired color somewhere like inside constants.dart like so:

```
const kPrimaryColor = Color(0xfffbba3d);
```

Then you can use ButtonStyle with opacity/transparency using .withOpacity() like so:

```
TextButton(
     style: ButtonStyle(
          overlayColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith(
            (states) => kPrimaryColor.withOpacity(0.3))),
                    onPressed: () => {},
                    child: 
                        Text(
                          'My Button',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16,
                              color: kPrimaryColor,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                        ),    
                  ),
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove splash
Make backgroundColor same foregroundColor

```
style: TextButton.styleFrom(
   backgroundColor: Colors.green,  // Button color
   foregroundColor: Colors.green,   // Splash color
),
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative to using `resolveWith` and providing an anonymous function like this:

```
ButtonStyle(
   overlayColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.red),
)
```

Instead, you can just use the named constructor `all` of `MaterialStateProperty`, which is syntactic sugar for the same effect:

```
ButtonStyle(
   overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red)
)
```

This is cleaner and has a better readability.