# Flutter 2.0 - How to change TextButton splash color when pressed?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

```
FlatButton is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Used TextButton instead.
```

On my previous `FlatButton` widget, I was able to changed the splash color when on pressed. But now I'm using `TextButton` widget, how can I change its color the efficient way on the `MaterialApp ThemeData` or directly on the `TextButton` widget.

Currenly this is my TextButton

```
TextButton(
  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
    primary: Colors.red,
    textStyle: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black45,
      fontFamily: "Courier Prime",
    ),
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Text(
    "Student",
    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
  ),
),
```

```
overlayColor is used to indicate that the button is focused, hovered, or pressed.
```

But I cant find this `overlayColor`

Comment: you can use `setState` to change color when pressed

Comment: @AkshayNayka , its the Splash color what i mean like when you pressed a button theres an accent colors slowly filling up the button. Its not the Button Color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
TextButton(            
 style: ButtonStyle(
  overlayColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.red),
  ),
 child: ..., 
)
```

reference to [Flutter TextButton splashColor property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64380867/flutter-textbutton-splashcolor-property)

Answer (score 11):

First keep in mind that the primary property on a TextButton sets the colour of its text and icon. It does not change the ripple color. Secondly in Textbutton there is no direct property to change splash color. So if you want to change splash color to transparent you can do it like this.

```
TextButton(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.________),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can quickly set the splash color of a `TextButton` using the helper method `TextButton.styleFrom()`. Note that this will actually set both the foreground color and splash color based on the foreground color, which in most of the cases is what you want:

```
TextButton(
  style: TextButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.red),
  child: const Text('Text Button'),
  onPressed: () {},
)
```

### [Live Demo](https://dartpad.dev/?id=9cd3d5d2ec2454c1a57552237a46e636&null_safety=true)

Comment: Thank bro, this way is faster & shorter than the way use ButtonStyle() like others recommended

Answer (score 0):

You can change Splash color like this:

```
            Theme(
              data: ThemeData(
                splashColor: Colors.red,
                highlightColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(.5),
              ),
              child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    "New theme splash",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {}),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [NearHuscarl's Anser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69089762/6280902). but
after flutter v3.1.0 you can implement like

```
TextButton(
  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
    backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
    foregroundColor: Colors.white
  ),
  child: const Center(child: Text('OK')),
  onPressed: () {},
)
```